# How to install Pantheon without messing up GNOME

Tags: 19.04, pantheon

I'd like to have Pantheon as another session option, next to GNOME and Ubuntu's GNOME variant.

Is there a way I could install Pantheon on Ubuntu 19.04 without messing up various parts of my system? (E.g. the theme changing, maximize and close window buttons changing placement, etc.)

(I would like a full-fledged system, not a system running in a VM)

Comment: Are you still looking for answers?

Answer (score 4):

I'm sharing my experience with installing pantheon desktop on top of Ubuntu Budgie 19.04. Ubuntu's main GNOME edition should work similarly.

---

First, add these two ppas **ppa:elementary-os/stable** and **ppa:elementary-os/os-patches**.

When you install the first ppa with this command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable`, it will create the repository source file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Edit that file to change the distro name from `disco` (19.04) to `bionic`. Then re-run `sudo apt update`

After installing both ppas, add Ubuntu 18.04's main repository source line. You can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or edit one of the elementary's source file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. Add this line (or any other bionic mirror of your choice)

```
# ubuntu bionic repo for some packages
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
```

Then run these

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elementary-desktop
```

---

### Bonus tips

Add elementary's appcenter's source to get some more elementary apps.

In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list`, add these

```
deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main
# deb-src http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main
```

Then refresh the package index and open appcenter to find curated elementary apps

Comment: Finally, worked like a charm!
After battling with this for months, not being able to revert fully to gnome, my system still reported 'ElementaryOS' despite the efforts. 
I gave it another chance following your answer, even though I am on Bionic 18.0.4 - thus I skipped the step to edit the file to change distro name from disco to bionic.
Thanks!

Comment: @arakno Glad it helped