# how to install pantheon-files on ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: 18.04, package-management, pantheon

what i did:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
$ sudo apt update
```

Ubuntu 18.04.3 Mate try install Pantheon-Files but get error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f pantheon-files

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pantheon-files : Depends: libcloudproviders0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: contractor but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: tumbler-plugins-extra but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

have try fine other way like snap or flatpak or appimage but no luck.

Comment: You need to contact package developers and ask them to lower the dependency version.

Comment: Try this approach here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138831/how-to-install-pantheon-without-messing-up-gnome
Then do `sudo apt-get install -f pantheon-files` and should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to enable universe repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and then you can manually download and install [newer version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libcloudproviders0) of the library with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libc/libcloudproviders/libcloudproviders0_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libcloudproviders0_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb
```

and then install pantheon-files with

```
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```